# Warn about unused imports in python with pycodestyle linter in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I cannot add warnings about unused imports (W0611 or W0614) in vscode with pycodestyle linter. 
I have tried to add

```
"--enable=W0614"
```

or the same with W0611 in the user settings in

```
python.linting.pycodestyleArgs
```

But it does not work as should be. Instead all linting stops until I remove this additionnal argument. 
Any help much appreciated !

Comment: I ended up adding flake8 as linter in settings.